# DNS Configuration Help for dedicated hosting server

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone

I currently have a dedicated server UBUNUT 10.04lts with my own email server, dns server, and web server all running from the same box.  I would like to love the DNS services off this box if at all possible and not have my own name servers hosted in my web server.

I was given 5 IP's from the hosting company. The network admin set my server up to be my own DNS server, email server, and web server.

My Domain is at godaddy.com but the DNS is managed on my server.
reverse DNS is set up through my dedicated hosting company as they have their own rDNS server.

I would like to move the DNS back to Godaddy and use their name servers.

My question is around what are the parameters I need to change in my bind zone files?

Currently, my records look like this:

```
$TTL      604800
@   IN   SOA   CDS0135NS.mydomain.com.  admin.mydomain.com.  {
               20110202
               6044800
               86400
               2419200
               604800  }

;
    IN   NS   ns1.mydomain.com
    IN   NS   ns2.mydomain.com
@   IN   A    111.111.11.111 (my server IP)
@   IN   AAAA ::1
www IN   A    111.111.11.111 (my server IP)
www.mydomain.com.  IN  A   111.111.11.111
ns  IN  A  111.111.11.111
ns1 IN  A  111.111.11.111
ns2 IN  A  111.111.11.111
ns1.mydomain.com   IN  A   111.111.11.111
ns2.mydomain.com   IN  A   111.111.11.111

mail  IN  A  111.111.11.111
mydomain.com.  IN  A  MX   10   mail.mydomain.com.

imap  IN  CNAME  mail
pop   IN  CNAME  mail 
pop3  IN  CNAME  mail
relay IN  CNAME  mail    
smtp  IN  CNAME  mail
```

Now when I park my DNS with godaddy, they will give me ns1.godaddy.domain.com, ns2.godaddy.domain.com.  They told me I would have to go into their control panel and put in my MX record (Which I would assume is my own mail.mydomain.com) and I would point their A record to my IP address of 111.111.11.111 within their control panel.  But what do I do with "@   IN   SOA   CDS0135NS.mydomain.com.  admin.mydomain.com."  do I leave it alone?

And for my rDNS, do I continue to have it run through my dedicated hosting providers rDNS or should I run that through godaddy?  Does my rDNS have anything to do with me changing the DNS hosted provider?

I am new to this and I have been reading as much as I could in the short time, and I have learned through my sys admin person.  But he is no longer available so I am kind of on my own to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a meaningful title :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rDNS records will remain with your hosting provider.  While they can delegate this, you won't be able to use standard techniques to setup the PTR records with GoDaddy.

I will use example.com for your domain as that is recommended domain for documentation.

Setup your MX for example.com to point to your mail server (mail.example.com).  Setup the IP address for mail.example.com as an A record.  You can create as many CNAME or A records as you want for this server, but mail is a good general purpose name that can be used in place of all the CNAMES you are using.

If you want to be able to browse example.com, you will need an A record for it.  Configure www.example.com as an A record.

Consider setting up TXT records for [SPF](http://www.openspf.org/).

If you have a global IPv6 address block, you can configure IPv6 and add AAAA record in addition to your A records.  Otherwise don't setup AAAA records.

GoDaddy will configure the SOA and NS records.

EDIT: Suggested temporary db contents.  Use the correct nameservers from GoDaddy, these may be incorrect.  Shut down bind after 2 days to a week.

When you move back to GoDaddy you will need to add address records for the domain, www, and mail as well as the MX record. This will have to be done through their web interface.  I have added suggested SPF records.  The records you need to add start with the first A record which is for your domain.

```
$TTL       1H
@      IN      SOA   ns1.godaddy.domain.com.  admin.mydomain.com.  {
               2011031200
               3H
               1H
               1W
               1H  }

       IN      NS   ns1.godaddy.domain.com
       IN      NS   ns2.godaddy.domain.com
       IN      A    111.111.11.111
       IN      MX   10   mail
       IN      TXT  "v=spf1 mx -all"

www    IN      A    111.111.11.111
       IN      TXT  "v=spf1 -all"
mail   IN      A    111.111.11.111
       IN      TXT  "v=spf1 A -all"
```

Once you have this setup try using the host command to check the values from godaddy. Start with `host -a mydomain.com ns1.godaddy.domain.com`.  Also check the www and mail addresses.  If they are resolving correctly and showing godaddys nameservers, then everything is setup.  It will take a couple of days for any record pointing at your host to age out of DNS cache.

Comment: Thank you. My question is, do I just replace my current mydomain.db file within my etc/bind/domain.db and edit the file to just have the statements for my A Record and MX record and delete all of the rest?  Then just restart the network?  What files do I need to change out besides this domain.db file?   


mail  IN  A  111.111.11.111
mydomain.com.  IN  A  MX   10   mail.mydomain.com.

Comment: Also do I need to do anything with my /etc/resolv.conf file?

Currently it has 

//nameserver  11.22.333.12
//nameserver  11.22.333.13

search mydomain.com
nameserver 111.111.11.111 (my ip address)

Comment: @Ubuntu User: I added a suggested transitional db file and info on setting up at GoDaddy.  GoDaddy won't use your db file, but you need to enter the information into their web interface.

Comment: @Ubutu User: I would remove the double slashes from the first two nameservers.  This will enable your providers nameservers.  Add double slashes in front of the last nameserver.  That nameserver will fail when you shut down the bind service.

Comment: Thank you.  So once I enter the information into Godaddy's control panel and point their SOA to my IP address.  My main concern is how can I get my email servers to use mail.mydomain.com so I can then put that into the godaddy's control panel to point to my mail MX record. I noticed in your example, you placed IN MX 10 mail and then followed up with IN TXT "v=spf1 mx -all"  Is this where I should potentially be placing ---  mail  IN  A  111.111.11.111  --- followed by another line:  
mydomain.com.  IN  A  MX   10   mail.mydomain.com.

Comment: @Ubuntu User:  GoDaddy should be your SOA as they will be your authoritive name servers.  Only A records should point at your name servers.  The SPF records go with the A records they follow: mydomain.com, www.mydomain.com, and mail.mydomain.com.  They allow mail from the MX (mail), none, and self.  The MX record applies to mydomain.com.

Comment: Thank you.  The only thing I do not understand is:  IN      TXT  "v=spf1 mx -all"


If I typed in the following, would it be considered accurate?

www IN   A    111.111.11.111 (my server IP)
www.mydomain.com.  IN  A   111.111.11.111

mail  IN  A  111.111.11.111
mydomain.com.  IN  A  MX   10   mail.mydomain.com.

Comment: Also, once I make this change, do I need to turn off my DNS services on my server?  And will it affect my email server if I do this?  I am using Citadel as my email server.

Comment: Once I do all of this, how do I shut off my bind?  Once I shut my bind off, will it affect my email server?

Comment: @Ubuntu User:  First use `/etc/init.d/bind9 stop`.  Then after a couple of days you can shut it down.  You could also reconfigure you bind server as a caching only server.  Your mail server doesn't depend on your bind, although it may be suggested.  If you are receiving and filtering mail a local DNS cache is useful.

Comment: My Network interface currently has the two dns-nameservers 11.22.111.22, 11.22.111.23 /etc/network/interfaces which are the two in the resolv.conf file.  Do I need to remove this?  or should I replace this line in my primary network interface with godaddy's name server ips?  I am not sure where I would get the ip's for the two name servers .. maybe do mytoolbox look up?

Thank you

Comment: @Ubuntu User:  Keep them as they are.  The dns-servers listed in resolv.conf have an entirely different purpose, than the name servers provided by GoDaddy.  The name servers in /etc/resolv.conf are caching servers for looking up addresses,  while those at GoDaddy are publishing servers.  GoDaddy's servers should be configured so that they will not work when used in /etc/resolve.conf.

Comment: @BillThor, is it possible to contact you and I could hire you or an hour or so to walk me through this process and teach me along the way?  I can be reached via my email at jim_kim87@yahoo.com

Thank you

Comment: Bill Thor helped me via chat on this.  I have to say he is better than anyone I have so far worked with.

All I can say is WOW!!!!   Thank you soo much Bill!!!! You are truely a great person and a very knowledgeable individual.  Even helped me with a person who was stealing page ranks by pointing his domain to my IP!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about the SOA record. GoDaddy will take care of that for you.
Also you do not need to worry about NS records, as they will also take care of these.

You need only to create the rest of your records.

Reverse DNS will stay at the owner of the IP block. No need to worry about that. This is because reverse DNS is really just normal DNS based on the resource record type PTR and they are placed in an in-addr.arpa zone, which is delegated by the owner of the IP block.

You just need to make sure that you have a forward record (A) matching the reverse. Like so.

```
11.11.11.11.in-addr.arpa   PTR  my.server.hostname.com # Your providers end
my.server.hostname.com     A    11.11.11.11 # Your end
```

Comment: What about my mail server and its records?  Right now it is set to mail.mydomain.com. for mx 10 with mail IN A my server IP.

Comment: So my zone file:  mydomain.com.db file can be pired out with just what you described?  So long as on the godaddy side is pointed to my IP address?  If you can be more explict .. since I am still learning that would be great.

Comment: so if my ip is 111.222.33.444 and my server name is CDS0135 and my domain is mydomain.com then my records will look like: 111.222.33.444.in-addr.arpa  PTR  CDS0135.mydomain.com (What is # at my provider end?) then CDS0135.mydomain.com  A  111.222.33.444

Comment: You don't need any PTR records with GoDaddy.  The records you have, all of them, except for SOA and NS, you create in the GoDaddy interface. And then you redelegate your domain to GoDaddy's nameservers. And then you're all set.

Comment: You need to ask your IP provider to set the PTR record for your mail server's ip address to point to mail.mydomain.com.  They need to resolve as fbh described.  Unless you have a globally routeable IPv6 address don't include an AAAA record.  An unreachable AAAA record will make you unreachable from some (most) IPv6 capable systems.  Unless you have another DNS server, you should use Godaddy to handle your DNS.